# Trying to induce a background blur over a portion of an image without affecting the text overlaying it

Tags: css, wordpress, blur

firstly, I'm a UI/UX designer, please excuse me for my poor CSS/HTML.
I'm trying to introduce a background blur under some text which is on an image. Currently the div is set to a slightly transparent red colour which creates this overlay. 
This is wordpress based and as such I'm trying to figure out a way to do this via CSS by inspecting the site in Chrome

Please look at the photos and descriptions for better understanding into what I am trying to do.

First image is the current situation
Second image (4) is the desired situation

Unfortunately my reputation isn't high enough to display more

[image]

[image]

Comment: post the code you have tried.

Comment: sorry but I didnt understand what is the problem and what is your objective; The question is also missing a relevant piece of code.

Comment: Seems like a [blur filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) would work, if something like [this old example](http://jsfiddle.net/ttumsmom/3/) achieves what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey guys.. again sorry for the lack of code, I don't have access to the code as it's wordpress and the reason why i'm doing this in the first place is because my wordpress guy is unavailable right now - I want to send him something that will work for our case

So under the text I would like to introduce a blur that is effectively applied to the image.The last CSS line sort of does that but blurs text too

` .home-slider-events .slide-event-detail {
    background: rgba(28, 171, 197, 0.85);
    padding: 60px 50px;
    height: 520px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
} `

Answer (score 1):

So based on what the user colonelsanders has commented, I was able to introduce a new div and blur the background!

Thanks everyone and sorry for the poor post

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any code so I'll have to guess.

If your main background is `fixed`, then you can add an extra element ( we'll call it "cover" ) in the element that you want the blurred background ( we'll call it "blur" ), stretch the "cover" to fill the "blur's" width and height, set the main background to the "cover" with `fixed` position, and use the blur filter on it.